# How to audit mysql changes

Tags: mysql, audit

Have table with 4 000 000 rows. Need audit any data changes in table. I create triggers for this table and audit all changes data,but is there any better way for audit changes in table ? And also one more question, how audit droped table,view,stored procedures,functions,triggers ? In sql server I can create ddl trigger but as I know mysql does not support it. My database is Mysql Community Edition

Comment: I use the Percona Audit Log Plugin for this purpose, it takes a bit of work to filter out just the stuff you need, but is very detailed. Downside - it only runs on Linux Databases (not Windows)

Comment: @IGGt but as i understand it is for percona server, not for mysql 5.6 community edition

Comment: No, it works fine on MySQL as well. I am running mainly MySQL 5.5 databases,